# Use SQL CONVERT within Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I use CONVERT from mysql within Doctrine.

```
$now = new \DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$selectedDate = new \DateTime($flightDate);
$selectedDate = $selectedDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query= $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->where('CONVERT(:selectedDate, DATE) + o.time >= :currentTime')
        ->setParameter('selectedDate', $selectedDate)
        ->setParameter('currentTime', $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setMaxResults(20)
        ->getQuery();
```

For which I get an error

> Error: Expected known function, got 'CONVERT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom dql function, you can read here for more information:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT` is not a valid doctrine extension.

> You can check all valid extensions [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

In this case you should use `DATE` + `DATEADD` extension

> You can always create [custom DQL functions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)